# Need to parse XML string that's returned from database stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have a stored procedure call that returns some XML in a field. There are other fields that return XML but only return one element within them. This new field is going to contain multiple elements that will need to be looped through to display a string for the end user.

Here is a sample of the XML that will be returned:

```
<Superbills>
    <Superbill>
        <SuperBillID>1</SuperBillID>
        <EventDate>2004-03-23T13:24:16</EventDate>
        <ProcCodes>
            <ProcCode>27096</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>76005</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>A4550</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>A4641</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>J3301</ProcCode>
        </ProcCodes>
    </Superbill>
    <Superbill>
        <SuperBillID>2</SuperBillID>
        <EventDate>2004-03-23T13:24:16</EventDate>
        <ProcCodes>
            <ProcCode>27096</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>76005</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>A4550</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>A4641</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>J3301</ProcCode>
        </ProcCodes>
    </Superbill>
    <Superbill>
        <SuperBillID>3</SuperBillID>
        <EventDate>2004-03-24T13:24:16</EventDate>
        <ProcCodes>
            <ProcCode>27096</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>76005</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>A4550</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>A4641</ProcCode>
            <ProcCode>J3301</ProcCode>
        </ProcCodes>
    </Superbill>
</Superbills>
```

I need to be able to loop through all the Superbill sets to output something similar to the following:

```
[EventDate] ([ProcCode], [ProcCode], [ProcCode], [ProcCode], [ProcCode])
[EventDate] ([ProcCode], [ProcCode], [ProcCode], [ProcCode], [ProcCode])
```

Basically, I need to build a comma separate string for each of the `ProcCode`s within the Superbill sets as well as parse out the event date to build one string for each one.

I've tried going through the `using XmlReader`, but that doesn't give me the individual lines for each "Superbill" element. It ends up giving me just the event dates together and then the `ProcCode`s together.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code as to where you are stuck with deserializing the xml?

Comment: Added the attempt using xmlreader.

Comment: Use XmlDocument.loadXML( strXML).  Then write an XSL to output the fields you need.

Comment: Or without XSL, use XmlDocment.loadXML, then use XPath like "//Superbill" in the selectNodes method to iterate through each.

Comment: `XmlReader` is a pain to use for tasks like this. Create and `XmlDocument` from the XML and select the elements using XPath or create an `XDocument` and use Linq2Xml to extract what you need.

Comment: @JLRishe I'm not as familiar with XPath as I probably need to be. Can you show an example with the example xml code in the question? XSL would be a little too much as this is an on demand report that is within a user control on a page so XPath would probably be the best way to go. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the Serializer approach...

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim XMLString As String = File.ReadAllText("SuperBills.xml")

        With New XmlSerializer(GetType(Superbills)).Deserialize(New IO.MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XMLString)))
            For Each SuperBill As Superbill In .Superbills
                Debug.Print("{0} ({1})", SuperBill.EventDate.ToShortDateString, Join(SuperBill.ProcCodes, ", "))
            Next
        End With
    End Sub
End Module

<XmlRoot()>
Partial Public Class Superbills
    <XmlElement("Superbill")>
    Public Property Superbills As Superbill()
End Class

Partial Public Class Superbill
    Public Property SuperBillID As Byte
    Public Property EventDate As Date

    <XmlArrayItem("ProcCode")>
    Public Property ProcCodes As String()
End Class
```

Is this what you were looking for?

```
3/23/2004 (27096, 76005, A4550, A4641, J3301)
3/23/2004 (27096, 76005, A4550, A4641, J3301)
3/24/2004 (27096, 76005, A4550, A4641, J3301)
```

Comment: I think so. The assumption on my end is that I'm not getting the XML from reading a file but as a value returned in a stored procedure from the database. In which case, I can modify the routine to accept a string parameter and then use that string paramater for Dim XMLString?

Comment: I have put this into my code, but it's giving me an error regarding the .Superbills in the for Each statement. I am in a user control code behind so the partial public classes are within the partial class for the user control page. I am not sure where these need to go with respect to nesting them.

Comment: Nevermind on the last comment. I had an extra close parentheses on the line above which was throwing everything off. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want only `EventData` and `ProcCode` values you can use Linq To Xml

```vb
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(yourString)

var eventsAndCodes = 
    doc.Descendants("Superbill").
        Select(Function(bill) 
                   Return New With
                   {
                       .EventData = bill.Element("EventDate").Value,
                       .ProcCodes = bill.Descendants("ProcCode").Select(Function(code) code.Value).ToList()
                   }
               End Function)

For Each data in eventsAndCodes
    ' Use values
    data.EventData
    data.ProcCodes
Next
```

Instead of anonymous type you can create your own for better readability

```vb
Public Class EventInfo
    Public Property EventDate As Date
    Public Property ProcCodes As List(Of String)
End Class
```

And method for retrieving data from `XElement`

```vb
Public Function CreateEventInfoFromXElement(element As XElement) As EventInfo
    Return New EventInfo With
    {
        .EventData = bill.Element("EventDate").Value,
        .ProcCodes = bill.Descendants("ProcCode").
                          Select(Function(code) code.Value).
                          ToList()
    }
End Function
```

Then use them

```vb
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(yourString)
Dim eventsData As IEnumerable(Of EventInfo) = 
    doc.Descendants("Superbill").Select(AddressOf CreateEventInfoFromXElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using LinqToXml:

```
var doc = XElement.Parse("...xml...");

var list = doc.XPathSelectElements("//EventDate")
    .Select(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Value).ToShortDateString() + ", (" +
    string.Join(", ", e.ElementsAfterSelf().First().Elements().Select(e2 => e2.Value)) +
    ")").ToList();
```

Converted to VB:

```
Dim doc as XElement = XElement.Parse("...xml...")

Dim list as List(of String) = doc.XPathSelectElements("//EventDate").
    Select(Function(e) DateTime.Parse(e.Value).ToShortDateString & 
    ", (" & String.Join(", ", e.ElementsAfterSelf.First.Elements.
    Select(Function(e2) e2.Value)) & ")").ToList
```

It's not exactly super pretty, but it works.  It searches the document for all `EventDate` elements, parses them as dates, and output the ShortDate format, then it takes all the elements inside the next sibling element and joins their values with commas.  It *does* assume that the `ProcCode` element will always be immediately after `EventDate`, and will fail if it isn't.  If that doesn't meet your requirement I can update it to be more resilient.

It produces a list of strings, one for each `EventDate`, in the following format:

> 3/23/2004, (27096, 76005, A4550, A4641, J3301)
>   3/23/2004, (27096, 76005, A4550, A4641, J3301)
>   3/24/2004, (27096, 76005, A4550, A4641, J3301)